# how to get the code using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have got the Values and key of Length, Breadth, and height in one object i.e "dim". and the 'units' in another object i.e "uni" now i want the output to be like this to be stored in result object.

```
result = {
"dimensions" : {

    "length" :{
          value:100,
          units:g   
        } 
    "breadth" :{
          "key":200
          "Units":g 
        }
     "height" :{
          "key":300,
          "Units":g     
        }

    }
}....
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use array with object parameter which further gives you option to add value and text or something like that. As

```
var obj = []; //
    for (i=0;i<num;i++){
      obj[i] = new myObject("param1","param2");
      obj[i].someProperty = value;
    }
```

Comment: i just need to get those two objects ("uni" and "dim") to be inserted into one object and displayed on the screen.